# Variável perde o valor em C

Tags: c

O código abaixo tem o comportamento esperado no caso de os valores serem informados correctamente. Mas, quando informo, por exemplo, na seguinte ordem: o `preco` igual a **1**, a `quantidade` igual a **-1** e, em seguida, a `quantidade` igual a **3**, o valor da variável `preco` passa a ser **0**.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    float preco = -1, totalAPagar;
    int quantidade = -1, jaPediuEntrada = 0;
    char mensagem[20];

    do {
        (jaPediuEntrada == 1) ? strcpy(mensagem, "Erro! ") : strcpy(mensagem, "");
        strcat(mensagem, "Insira um preco: ");
        printf(mensagem);
        scanf("%f", &preco);
        jaPediuEntrada = 1;
    } while (preco <= 0);

    jaPediuEntrada = 0;

    do {
        (jaPediuEntrada == 1) ? strcpy(mensagem, "Erro! ") : strcpy(mensagem, "");
        strcat(mensagem, "Insira uma quantidade: ");
        printf(mensagem);
        scanf("%d", &quantidade);
        jaPediuEntrada = 1;
    } while(quantidade <= 0);

    /*Debug*/
    printf("\nO preco e igual a %.2f.", preco);
    printf("\nA quantidade e igual a %d.\n", quantidade);

    totalAPagar = preco * quantidade;

    printf("O total a pagar e igual a %.2f.", totalAPagar);

    return(0);
}
```

Alguém sabe explicar o motivo desse comportamento do programa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeira coisa que reparei:

`"Erro! Insira um preco: "` precisa de 24 bytes ... mas a tua `mensagem` só tem espaço para 20.

Comment: Era isso mesmo, @pmg. Obrigado pela rápida resposta. Mudei a mensagem mas esqueci-me de mudar o tamanho da cadeia de char. Obrigado! O problema relatado era, portanto, um efeito colateral.